# Can someone guide me through how to use JButtons?

Tags: jbutton

I really have no idea how to use JButtons.  I'm trying to create a window to determine stats for a character, and have the program give some feedback.  However, it doesn't give feedback properly, and I can't figure out how to make it so the buttons actually make it give the feedback.  Also, if there are any other tips anyone has on how to improve my code, feedback would be most welcome.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class CharacterStats
    {
        public static String validityMessage = " ";


        public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                // Create the window
                JFrame window = new JFrame("Determining Character Stats");
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.setSize(1000, 500);
                window.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6, 20, 20));
                window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                // Define font and spinner models
                Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 14);
                SpinnerNumberModel chaModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel conModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel coorModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel enModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel expModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel heModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel loModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel siModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel smModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel spModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel stModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel thoModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel toModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);
                SpinnerNumberModel wiModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, 0, 28, 1);

                // Create main next and back buttons
                JToggleButton nextWindowButton = new JToggleButton("Next");
                JToggleButton validityButton = new JToggleButton("Check vailidity");
                /*Make validityButton run checkValidty() and store checkVailidty()'s
                 * return value in validityMessage*/


                // Create spinners
                JSpinner charismaSpinner = new JSpinner(chaModel);
                JSpinner constitutionSpinner = new JSpinner(conModel);
                JSpinner coordinationSpinner = new JSpinner(coorModel);
                JSpinner enduranceSpinner = new JSpinner(enModel);
                JSpinner experienceSpinner = new JSpinner(expModel);
                JSpinner hearingSpinner = new JSpinner(heModel);
                JSpinner loyaltySpinner = new JSpinner(loModel);
                JSpinner sightSpinner = new JSpinner(siModel);
                JSpinner smellSpinner = new JSpinner(smModel);
                JSpinner speedSpinner = new JSpinner(spModel);
                JSpinner strengthSpinner = new JSpinner(stModel);
                JSpinner thoughtSpinner = new JSpinner(thoModel);
                JSpinner touchSpinner = new JSpinner(toModel);
                JSpinner wisdomSpinner = new JSpinner(wiModel);

                // Create spinner labels
                JLabel charismaLabel = new JLabel("Charisma(Cha):");
                JLabel constitutionLabel = new JLabel("Constitution(Con):");
                JLabel coordinationLabel = new JLabel("Coordination(Coor):");
                JLabel enduranceLabel = new JLabel("Endurance(En):");
                JLabel experienceLabel = new JLabel("Experience(Exp):");
                JLabel hearingLabel = new JLabel("Hearing(He):");
                JLabel loyaltyLabel = new JLabel("Loyalty(Lo):");
                JLabel sightLabel = new JLabel("Sight(Si):");
                JLabel smellLabel = new JLabel("Smell(Sm):");
                JLabel speedLabel = new JLabel("Speed(Sp):");
                JLabel strengthLabel = new JLabel("Strength(St):");
                JLabel thoughtLabel = new JLabel("Thought(Tho):");
                JLabel touchLabel = new JLabel("Touch(To):");
                JLabel wisdomLabel = new JLabel("Wisdom(Wi):");

                // Format labels
                charismaLabel.setFont(f);
                constitutionLabel.setFont(f);
                coordinationLabel.setFont(f);
                enduranceLabel.setFont(f);
                experienceLabel.setFont(f);
                hearingLabel.setFont(f);
                loyaltyLabel.setFont(f);
                sightLabel.setFont(f);
                smellLabel.setFont(f);
                speedLabel.setFont(f);
                strengthLabel.setFont(f);
                thoughtLabel.setFont(f);
                touchLabel.setFont(f);
                wisdomLabel.setFont(f);

                // Create information labels
                JTextField validityLabel = new JTextField(validityMessage);

                // Format window
                window.add(charismaLabel);
                window.add(charismaSpinner);
                window.add(constitutionLabel);
                window.add(constitutionSpinner);
                window.add(coordinationLabel);
                window.add(coordinationSpinner);
                window.add(enduranceLabel);
                window.add(enduranceSpinner);
                window.add(experienceLabel);
                window.add(experienceSpinner);
                window.add(hearingLabel);
                window.add(hearingSpinner);
                window.add(loyaltyLabel);
                window.add(loyaltySpinner);
                window.add(sightLabel);
                window.add(sightSpinner);
                window.add(smellLabel);
                window.add(smellSpinner);
                window.add(speedLabel);
                window.add(speedSpinner);
                window.add(strengthLabel);
                window.add(strengthSpinner);
                window.add(thoughtLabel);
                window.add(thoughtSpinner);
                window.add(touchLabel);
                window.add(touchSpinner);
                window.add(wisdomLabel);
                window.add(wisdomSpinner);
                window.add(nextWindowButton);
                window.add(validityButton);
                window.add(validityLabel);

                // Public variables for spinners
                Object charisma = charismaSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.charisma = (int) charisma;
                Object constitution = constitutionSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.constitution = (int) constitution;
                Object coordination = coordinationSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.coordination = (int) coordination;
                Object endurance = enduranceSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.endurance = (int) endurance;
                Object experience = experienceSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.experience = (int) experience;
                Object hearing = hearingSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.hearing = (int) hearing;
                Object loyalty = loyaltySpinner.getValue();
                PVD.loyalty = (int) loyalty;
                Object sight = sightSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.sight = (int) sight;
                Object smell = smellSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.smell = (int) smell;
                Object speed = speedSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.speed = (int) speed;
                Object strength = strengthSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.strength = (int) strength;
                Object thought = thoughtSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.thought = (int) thought;
                Object touch = touchSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.touch = (int) touch;
                Object wisdom = wisdomSpinner.getValue();
                PVD.wisdom = (int) wisdom;

                // Display window
                window.setVisible(true);
            }


    public static String checkValidity()
        {
            double cha = PVD.charisma * 0.5;
            double con = PVD.constitution;
            double coor = PVD.coordination * 1.5;
            double en = PVD.endurance * 1.5;
            double exp = PVD.experience;
            double he = PVD.hearing * 0.5;
            double lo = PVD.loyalty * 0.5;
            double si = PVD.sight * 1.5;
            double sm = PVD.smell * 0.5;
            double sp = PVD.speed;
            double st = PVD.strength;
            double tho = PVD.thought * 2.0;
            double to = PVD.touch * 1.5;
            double wi = PVD.wisdom;
            double sum = cha + con + coor + en + exp + he + lo + si + sm + sp + st + tho + to + wi;
            double remainingPoints = 180 - sum;
            if (sum <= 180)
                {
                    return remainingPoints + " stat points remaining";
                }
            else
                {
                    return "You used " + remainingPoints + " too many stat points.";
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a button show you the feedback, you have to add an onclick Listener to that Button.

Example

```
private void buttonFeeder(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
        // Add your feedback here
    }
```

Note: there are other ways to create an OnClickListener. This is just an example

Comment: Sorry, those were supposed to be JButtons.  Dunno why I had Toggle in there.
But anyway, I redeclared it as a private button for multi-method uses, fyi.  Here's my code now:
    nextWindowButton = new JButton("Next");
    nextWindowButton.addActionListener(null);
However, since the button is a static button, I can't put "this" in place of "null" there.  What exactly am I supposed to do to fix that so this will work:
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
     if (e.getSource() == validityButton)
      {
       validityMessage = checkValidity();
      }
    }

Comment: Before `this` can work you have to implement `ActionListener`.  Example `public class calc extends JFrame implements ActionListener `